# How are types in FP fundamentally different than an object in OOP?

Tags: functional-programming, elixir

Forgive my noobness as I'm new to FP. Been working with Elixir, so I tagged it.

When I use Elixir's iex, I can inspect a variable's type using `i`. e.g. `i "hello"` shows me I can use `String` module's functions on it. I can do `String.downcase "HELLO"` which seems exactly like sending a message to an object that returns another object, but expressed in a different way to appear like a mathematical function. The `i` helper also seems like checking the class of an object which then helps me figure out all the methods available in that object.

I understand immutability is a key feature in functional programming. I can do immutability easily with many OO languages too, but the onus is on the programmer.

I've been reading Elixir books and blogs that recommend I forget my OO mindset and think fundamentally differently. I just don't get how they're fundamentally different and require a change in mindset when the only difference is immutability.

Comment: Types are orthogonal to the principles of FP (immutability, referential transparency, etc). There are functional dynamically typed languages like clojure and erlang. Part of your confusion is that some statically-typed OO languages \*coughJava\*cough overload the idea of a class to represent namespaces, user-defined types, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question may be more precisely specified as

> "What is the difference between classes and algebraic data types?"

It sounds like you know what an object and a class is, so you could complete the puzzle by reading up on ADTs:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type

Another key to understanding the difference between ADTs and classes is that classes deal with encapsulation of data AND methods, whereas ADTs are usually limited to only data. Note, however, that the modern trend is to mix the 2, see e.g. Scala's case classes.

Comment: I guess I grouped the concept of a type and programming paradigm into the same bucket when comparing the concepts as Jared pointed out. Rephrasing the question helps and I've progressed a bit, but I'm still on my quest to figuring out what they really mean.

Answer (score 1):

The i helper function does not "check the class of an object", it is basically a Protocol that operates on the core term types in Elixir. Every data value in Elixir is either one of these types or a composition of them.

```
[Atom, Integer, Float, BitString, Regexp, PID, Function, Reference, Port, Tuple, List, Map]
```

The i command does a little extra inspection to distinguish between variations of these types that are part of the standard library, such as Structs and helping with the erlang char_list problem. It cannot reach
much beyond that; if you use i with a complex composed type, all 
it knows about is the top level of the composition.

If you confine yourself to just these basics and the standard library, the difference to OO is not that apparent. However, where you really need to leave OO thinking behind is when you start composing data structures specific to your code.

There is no way[1] to sub-class or sub-type modules in Elixir. There's no Monkey Patching; no way to add new functions to String. While you can use Modules and Structs to duplicate single objects and write code that at first glance looks OO, once you cross a certain level of complexity that way of thinking falls apart.

What the admonitions about OO thinking are aimed at is the larger architecture of your code. Elixir is easiest when you ask these questions:

What are my data structures?

What transformations do I need to make on those data structures?

You'll get in trouble if you start thinking the OO way.

What are my nouns?

What are my verbs for each noun?

While these questions appear similar at first glance, there is a difference in that the functions are not intrinsic to the data. You could potentially apply any function from any module to your data. This decoupling of data and functions is the key difference.

[1]- Elixir is flexible enough that you could implement some kind of OO system in it if you tried hard enough.

Comment: It's starting to make sense combined with other answers and this was the most helpful. I need more experience to get an intuitive understanding of the difference. Any suggestion of an Elixir open source project with clean FP design would be helpful.